# how to change my icon layout to flex on css

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, formatting

I'm trying to change my icons to flex but that didn't work. This was my original CSS code:

```
.recipe-icons {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr); 
  gap: 1rem;
  margin: 2rem 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

I also tried setting display to flex, justify-content to center and all that but that didn't work either. How can I fix this? This is my html code for my icons:

```
div class="recipe-icons">
            <article>
              <!-- single recipe icon -->
              <i class="fas fa-clock"></i>
              <h5>prep time</h5>
              <p>30 min.</p>
              <!-- single recipe icon -->
              <i class="far fa-clock"></i>
              <h5>cook time</h5>
              <p>15 min.</p>
              <!-- single recipe icon -->
              <i class="fas fa-user-friends"></i>
              <h5>servings</h5>
              <p>6 servings</p>
              <!-- recipe tags -->
              <div class="recipe-tags">
                Tags: <a href="tag-template.html">beef</a>
                <a href="tag-template.html">breakfast</a>
                <a href="tag-template.html">pancakes</a>
                <a href="tag-template.html">food</a>
              </div>
            </article>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an alternative way of doing something like that using `display: flex;`
Also you should surround the elements in a div to group them.
Working example https://jsfiddle.net/r5Lfcbh8/1/

Html:

```
<article>
  <div class="recipe-icons">
    <div class="iconRow">
      <i class="fas fa-clock"></i>
      <h5>prep time</h5>
      <p>30 min.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="iconRow">
      <i class="far fa-clock"></i>
      <h5>cook time</h5>
      <p>15 min.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="iconRow">
      <i class="fas fa-user-friends"></i>
      <h5>servings</h5>
      <p>6 servings</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="recipe-tags">
    <span>Tags:</span>
    <a href="tag-template.html">beef</a>
    <a href="tag-template.html">breakfast</a>
    <a href="tag-template.html">pancakes</a>
    <a href="tag-template.html">food</a>
  </div>
</article>
```

And css:

```
article, .recipe-icons, .recipe-tags {
  display: flex;
}

article {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.recipe-tags {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.recipe-tags > * {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.recipe-icons > .iconRow {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.recipe-icons > .iconRow > * {
  margin: 5px 0;
}
```